# How to set multiple email in edittext like Gmail app?

Tags: android, email, edit

I want to add multiple email like gmail "To:" format. I want to edit and delete that email.Please help me in this problem.
I had searched too much but can't get any solution.

[gmail screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WdF5j.png)

I want like this attached screen shot.

Thank you.

Comment: use recycler view  inside  email layout

Comment: https://github.com/DoodleScheduling/android-material-chips 
what you want to do is possible with chip layout. Use this,this will help to achieve what you want....

Answer (score 0):

You could use this library : [TokenAutoComplete](https://github.com/splitwise/TokenAutoComplete)

Sample usage :

```
public class TokenActivity extends Activity {
ContactsCompletionView completionView;
Person[] people;
ArrayAdapter<Person> adapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    people = new Person[]{
            new Person("Marshall Weir", "marshall@example.com"),
            new Person("Margaret Smith", "margaret@example.com"),
            new Person("Max Jordan", "max@example.com"),
            new Person("Meg Peterson", "meg@example.com"),
            new Person("Amanda Johnson", "amanda@example.com"),
            new Person("Terry Anderson", "terry@example.com")
    };

    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Person>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, people);

    completionView = (ContactsCompletionView)findViewById(R.id.searchView);
    completionView.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

}

Complete usage can be found in the [Readme file](https://github.com/splitwise/TokenAutoComplete/blob/master/README.md)

Comment: This is work only for delete. I can not edit data using https://github.com/splitwise/TokenAutoComplete